# TypeError: must be real number, not str. But the data in int/float

Tags: python, error-handling, syntax-error, gridsearchcv

This is a section of my code. Please help removing the error

```
def result_using_non_tree_classifier(x,x_test,y,y_test):
    kf = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=None)
    scores= []   #to hold the scores
    algos1={'KNN' : {'model' : KNeighborsClassifier(n_jobs= -1) , 
                    'param' : {'n_neighbors' : np.arange(1,20,3).tolist() , 'weights' :['distance', 'uniform']}
                    }, 
        
        'SVC' : {'model' : SVC(max_iter= 10000),
                 'param' : {'kernel' : ['linear', 'poly', 'rbf'], 'gamma' : ['scale', 'auto']}
                },
        
        'SGD' : {'model' : SGDClassifier(),
                'param' : {'penalty' : ['l2', 'l1', 'elasticnet'], 'loss' : ['hinge','log','modified_huber','perceptron']}
                },
        
        'GaussianNB' : {'model': GaussianNB(),
                        'params':{}
                       }
       }
    for algo_name, params in algos1.items() :
       Grid1 = GridSearchCV(params['model'], params['param'], cv=kf, return_train_score=False)
       Grid1.fit(x, y)  #error occuring here
       ypred= Grid1.predict(x_test)
       scores.append({
        'model' : algo_name,
        'best_score': Grid1.best_score_ ,
        'best_parameter' : Grid1.best_params_
                })
    return pd.DataFrame(scores,columns=['model','best_score','best_params'])
result_using_non_tree_classifier(x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test) #calling the function

TypeError
```

Traceback (most recent call last)

```
<ipython-input-27-ce952cde5d5a> in <module>()
     28         })
     29     return pd.DataFrame(scores,columns=['model','best_score','best_params'])
---> 30 result_using_non_tree_classifier(x_train.astype(int),x_test,y_train.astype(int),y_test)

<ipython-input-27-ce952cde5d5a> in result_using_non_tree_classifier(x, x_test, y, y_test)
     20     for algo_name, params in algos1.items() :
     21         Grid1 = GridSearchCV(params['model'], params['param'], cv=kf, return_train_score=False)
**---> 22         Grid1.fit(x, y)**
     23         ypred= Grid1.predict(x_test)
     24         scores.append({



sklearn\svm\libsvm.pyx in sklearn.svm.libsvm.fit()

**TypeError: must be a real number, not str**
```

> The data is in int and float format. But, I don't know where this str
> is coming from.
> This is the complete error.
> https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/glass . This is the source link.
> The data is downloaded from Kaggle.
> It is a very big code so, I have to write some stuff other than code.
> Because it is not accepting!

Comment: Please show the full traceback

Comment: @Barmar Uploaded the Traceback.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).